# Im new to python n trying this out on my own as a personal project. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def close_window():
    root.destroy()
    exit()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x210")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Calculate Sale of Shares")

#Input box to key in value of shares
quantity = tkinter.Label (root, text="Quantity of Share").pack()
quantity = tkinter.Entry(root).pack()


#Input box to key in value of cost
cost = tkinter.Label (root, text="Cost per share").pack()
cost = tkinter.Entry(root).pack()

#Input box to key in value of sale
sell = tkinter.Label (root, text="Selling price per share").pack()
sell = tkinter.Entry(root).pack()

def calculator():
    global buying_price
    buying_price = float(sell.get()) * float(quantity.get()) - float(cost.get()) * float(quantity.get())
    print (buying_price)

#Button to click to calculate total profit/loss
button_widget = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Calculate P/L", width=15, command=calculator)
button_widget.pack()

button_clear = tkinter.Button(root, text="Clear", width=15)
button_clear.pack()

button_exit = tkinter.Button(root, text="Exit", width=15, command=close_window)
button_exit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File ".\tktest1.py", line 33, in calculator
    buying_price = float(sell.get()) * float(quantity.get()) - float(cost.get()) * float(quantity.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: What does `pack()` return?

Comment: @khelwood As I said in my answer, when you use `.pack()` on the same line as the widget initialization, the object will be worth a NoneType.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that is on this line: `quantity = tkinter.Entry(root).pack()`. If you put the `.pack()` on the same line, the variable `quantity` will be a NoneType.

To fix that, put them on separate lines.

Code:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def close_window():
    root.destroy()
    exit()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x210")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Calculate Sale of Shares")

#Input box to key in value of shares
quantity = tkinter.Label (root, text="Quantity of Share")
quantity.pack()
quantity2 = tkinter.Entry(root)
quantity2.pack()


#Input box to key in value of cost
cost = tkinter.Label (root, text="Cost per share").pack()
cost2 = tkinter.Entry(root)
cost2.pack()

#Input box to key in value of sale
sell = tkinter.Label (root, text="Selling price per share").pack()
sell2 = tkinter.Entry(root)
sell2.pack()

def calculator():
    global buying_price
    buying_price = float(sell2.get()) * float(quantity2.get()) - float(cost2.get()) * float(quantity2.get())
    print (buying_price)

#Button to click to calculate total profit/loss
button_widget = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Calculate P/L", width=15, command=calculator)
button_widget.pack()

button_clear = tkinter.Button(root, text="Clear", width=15)
button_clear.pack()

button_exit = tkinter.Button(root, text="Exit", width=15, command=close_window)
button_exit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i hv managed to overcome the problem n complete the program. thank you